# How to use Apache vhost URL in Docker PHP container

Tags: php, apache, docker, curl

I need to perform a `cURL` request from within PHP.

I don't know to access my project from inside the PHP container. `myproject.local` of course doesn't work as that configuration is set in the `/etc/hosts` file on my machine.

Apache and PHP-FPM are separate containers. Configuration below.

**Apache virtualhosts**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject.local
    ServerAlias www.myproject.local
    
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://192.168.0.33:9000/usr/local/apache2/my/project$1
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/my/project
    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/my/project>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myproject.local
    ServerAlias www.myproject.local

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
    
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://192.168.0.33:9000/usr/local/apache2/my/project$1
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/my/project
    <Directory /usr/local/apache2/my/project>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    apache:
        container_name: my-project-web
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        networks:
            public_net:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.0.11
    php:
        container_name: my-project-php
        depends_on:
            - apache
        networks:
            public_net:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.0.33
networks:
    public_net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can connect between containers within one Docker-Compose-Environment by their names. No need to assign static IP addresses.

For your example from the PHP-Container to the Apache-Container with *http://apache/*. Or from you Apache config to the PHP-FPM with *fcgi://php:9000*.

But keep in mind, making requests on your own webserver is bad practise!

Comment: This will not work in my case since on the production server, I'm not using Docker.

Can you please elaborate on "making requests on your own webserver is bad practise"?

Comment: Imagine your webserver is processing a user request. While processing this request another requests is started by your code. So your webserver is busy with 2 requests for one user, beside the caused overhead with networking, request processing, ... Now image your webserver receives 50 simultaneous requests and your code multiplies these requests by factor 2! So your webserver will be kinda busy.